# How do I use SharePlusLinuxPlugin?

Tags: linux, flutter, dart, share-plus

I'm trying to open an image from memory with the default image viewer on Linux.
The class is part of the [share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) package. I can't figure out how to define the required `UrlLauncherPlatform` property.

I want to use it like this:

`SharePlusLinuxPlugin(urlLauncher).shareXFiles([XFile.fromData(img)]);`

I have googled this class, didn't find any usage examples.

Answer (score 0):

From the [source code on Github](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/blob/135ec421060027e4dc99ac527782e883b7d376ae/packages/share_plus/share_plus/lib/src/share_plus_linux.dart), it looks like `shareXFiles()` has not been implemented on Linux. To quote:

```
Future<ShareResult> shareXFiles(
    List<XFile> files, {
    String? subject,
    String? text,
    Rect? sharePositionOrigin,
  }) {
    throw UnimplementedError(
      'shareXFiles() has not been implemented on Linux.',
    );
  }
```

The same is true for the `shareFiles()` method.

---

Aside from that, there is usually no need to call `SharePlusLinuxPlugin` directly. The `Share` class is configured in such a way that it automatically detects the platform that it is running on

Comment: yeah I know that `shareXFiles()` doesn't work on Linux, I just hoped that I could use `SharePlusLinuxPlugin` somehow. Do you know any other way to somehow share/open file on linux?